# Compare letters no matter the order SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I compare two strings if the order is not important in SQL Server?

So if I have for example two names:

```
Column 1        | Column 2
___________________________________
John Doe        | Doe, John
Stella Maris    | Maris, Stella
Nima Lima       | Lima, Nima
Jensen, James   | James Jensen
Katrina Blade   | Katrina the Blade
```

So that it says that all except the last one are identical?

It's not possible with just a `CASE WHEN [Column 1] = [Column 2] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` statement. Is it perhaps possible to tokenize the names into letters, run it through a cleaning function to remove punctuation and then compare if the letters which I then put in order are equal? Can this be done in SQL?

Comment: This is not a problem suitable for SQL.  You would probably need to write your own comparison function, if you need to do this in the database.

Comment: Those are different strings. There's no order involved here. I suspect you mean "split the strings using space or comma as separators, then try to match the words". This sounds a bit like free-text search using one or the other column as the search term

Comment: you need to decide what your rules would be to allow them to be the same - at the moment you've got slightly fuzzy rules - you might want to first remove commas, then start to think about how many names there can be, and then if any order becomes a match - I don't know an easy way though - with two names, it's not too bad, use a CTE to strip the commas and get A1 and A2 via string functions - then you've got logic to write for matching names

Comment: In addition to splitting the strings you need to figure out what words you want to eliminate. In your last example you would exclude "the". Are there other words to exclude?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That, I believe, is OP's point. I can see, as a human, that each of these match between Column1 and Column2, but the question is how do we tell the computer to tell when they match and when they don't. For instance, split out the first and last WORD into their own column for each input column (resulting in 4 columns). Then compare different combinations of those (first to last OR last to first OR last to last OR first to first). Alterntively apply some algorithm to compare like Levenshtein distance or ngram and set a threshold of acceptability from the output.

Comment: Of course, none of those are simple to implement and it's questionable if SQL or even your RDBMS is the right place to be doing this work (to @GordonLinoff's point)

Comment: @JNevill and that's what's not possible with SQL at all. Edit distance is unsuitable here, all entries have a very large distance between each other. FTS operations on the other hand like CONTAINS, FREETEXT etc would find them almost identical

Comment: There are plenty of Levenshtein distance UDF examples out there. Again, I think removing garbage words, splitting the results out to first/last for each column, then doing a levenshtein distance against different combinations would give a pretty high yield here. But... this seems like a problem that is already solved in other pieces of software so it's probably just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think we all agree that this is no SQL question really. For looking for a comma and swapping the substrings before and after can be done in about every SQL dialect, as well as any programming language. And the same applies for removing substrings like ' the '. So it all boils down to finding an algorithm. 
@mrPy: Think of what series of checks and related string manipulations you want to apply to the strings before comparing them. Once you got these, translate this to SQL. Look up string functions for SQL Server if you want to do this in SQL.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. This helps a lot!

Comment: When columns contain data in a variety of different formats, like [Column 1] and [Column 2] then the data is not even in First Normal Form (1NF).  Which means bad table design.

Comment: It is bad table design Zorkolot, and I'm stuck with it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a really interesting comment string going on above, but OP's requirements seem simple enough: does first name + last name in the formats [first last] or [last, first] match? If it is that simple, you can just re-format column1 and column2 like so:

```
CREATE table #T1 (column1 nvarchar(max), column2 nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO #T1 (column1, column2)
VALUES
('John Doe', 'Doe, John')
,('Stella Maris', 'Maris, Stella')
,('Nima Lima', 'Lima, Nima')
,('Jensen, James', 'James Jensen')
,('Katrina Blade', 'Katrina the Blade')

SELECT column1, column2,
    RTRIM(
        LTRIM(
            SUBSTRING(column1, CHARINDEX(',', column1) + 1, LEN(column1) - CHARINDEX(',', column1)) 
            + CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(',', column1) > 0 
            THEN ' ' + LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX(',', column1) - 1) 
            ELSE ''
            END
            -- or if using SQL Server 2017 TRIM(',', LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX(',', column1)))
        )
    ),
    RTRIM(
        LTRIM(
            SUBSTRING(column2, CHARINDEX(',', column2) + 1, LEN(column2) - CHARINDEX(',', column2)) 
            + CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(',', column2) > 0 
            THEN ' ' + LEFT(column2, CHARINDEX(',', column2) - 1) 
            ELSE ''
            END
            -- or if using SQL Server 2017 TRIM(',', LEFT(column2, CHARINDEX(',', column2)))
        )
    )  
FROM #T1
```

Comment: Thanks @zambonee, this solves a big part of the problem ;). If there comes no other answer, I will mark this as the answer